# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'URL' with no arguments - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

Receive error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'URL' with no arguments

Following is the code -

```
 var databasePath = URL()
```

I have declare this variable globally. Also tried for

```
 var databasePath: URL!
 if let url = NSURL().absoluteURL { //error 1- Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
 databasePath = url //error2 - Variable used within its own initial value
 }
```

Receive above 2 errors if write above code as replacement of var databasePath = URL() .

I am beginner in Swift. Please let me know the solution.

Comment: URLs are immutable objects. You should do sth like: `URL(fileURLWithPath: "/tmp/db")`

Answer (score 2):

The URL initializer must have an argument.

Basically there are two types:

- An URL in the file system

  ```
  let databaseURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/path/to/file.ext")
  ```
- An URL with an explicit scheme (e.g. `http`, `ftp` etc)

  ```
  let databaseURL = URL(string:"http://myserver/path/to/file.ext")!
  ```

  If the URL is guaranteed to be valid it can be unwrapped (`!`) otherwise use optical bindings (`if let`)

Answer (score 1):

Swift- 5 Easy way

```
var fileDownloadedURL = URL(string: "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare url in this way

var url: URL = NSURL() as URL